# ScenKit eulerAngles strange values during rotation

Tags: swift, rotation, angle, scenekit

I'm rotating a SCNNode using the following lines:

```
 let rotate = SCNAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), aroundAxis:SCNVector3Make(0, 1, 0), duration: NSTimeInterval(10.0))
    let repeat = SCNAction.repeatActionForever(rotate)
    node.runAction(repeat)
```

and i print the eulerAngles.y of the node in the render method:

```
let rad = Double(node.eulerAngles.y)        
var angleInDegrees = fmodf(360.0 + -Float(rad) * (180.0 / Float(M_PI)), 360.0)
println("eulerAngles.y rad:\(rad) degree:\(angleInDegrees)")
```

but I get strange values during rotation like the following:

```
...
eulerAngles.y rad:-1.38788688182831 degree:79.5201
eulerAngles.y rad:-1.40567290782928 degree:80.5391 
eulerAngles.y rad:-1.4227991104126 degree:81.5204
eulerAngles.y rad:-1.44030773639679 degree:82.5236
eulerAngles.y rad:-1.45790004730225 degree:83.5315
eulerAngles.y rad:-1.47438871860504 degree:84.4763
eulerAngles.y rad:-1.49130213260651 degree:85.4453
eulerAngles.y rad:1.57079637050629 degree:270.0
eulerAngles.y rad:1.57079637050629 degree:270.0
eulerAngles.y rad:1.57079637050629 degree:270.0
eulerAngles.y rad:1.57079637050629 degree:270.0
eulerAngles.y rad:1.57079637050629 degree:270.0
eulerAngles.y rad:1.57079637050629 degree:270.0
eulerAngles.y rad:1.57079637050629 degree:270.0
eulerAngles.y rad:1.57079637050629 degree:270.0
eulerAngles.y rad:-1.49359321594238 degree:85.5766
eulerAngles.y rad:-1.47716772556305 degree:84.6355
...
```

I don't understant why 270 is printed. Can you explain me or there another way
to get the correct angle of the node?

Answer (score 6):

That's how Euler angles work. They have two quirks (I'll refer to `x`, `y`, and `z` as `pitch`, `yaw`, and `roll` respectively):

- `roll` and `yaw` increase with counterclockwise rotation from 0 to π (180 degrees) and then jump to -π (-180 degrees) and continue to increase to 0 as the rotation completes a circle; but `pitch` increases to π/2 (90 degrees) and then decreases to 0, then decreases to -π/2 (-90 degrees) and increases to 0.
- Values become inaccurate in certain orientations. In particular, when `pitch` is ±90 degrees, `roll` and `yaw` become erratic. See the [wikipedia article on gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

Comment: Thanks, there is solution in order to know the angle also with some approximation? I'like to fire an event (using NSNotificationCenter) when the node is orintented to North,South,East and Ovest.

Comment: Well, that's why there's a `rotation` property and an `orientation` property.