# Calculate Y-axis angle between World Origin and ARCamera

Tags: swift, matrix, scenekit, arkit

First of all, I feel like this question is pretty simple and that I am just lacking some mathematical knowledge, it feels like a formula would be able to give me the answer, however I cannot find it anywhere.

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate the Y-axis angle between the `ARCamera` and the `World Origin`.

I thought at first that I could use a `SCNNode` and its `eulerAngles` property as followed:

```
let node = SCNNode()
node.transform = sceneView.pointOfView!.camera.worldTransform
print(node.eulerAngles.y) // Angle given is always between [-π/2, π/2]
```

It is explained in a bit more detail here: [ScenKit eulerAngles strange values during rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126632/scenkit-eulerangles-strange-values-during-rotation)

I also know that the node has a `rotation` property that is a non-normalized quaternion and that a rotation on the Y-axis could also be done by rotating X-axis and Z-axis at the same time.

Is there is a way to get the angle from the world origin to the `-z` of the camera using the `transform`, `rotation`, or `orientation` properties?

It seems like what I am looking for would be a swift implementation of the Unity Vector3.SignedAngle function: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SignedAngle.html

```
    Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;
    Vector3 forward = transform.forward;
    float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(targetDir, forward, Vector3.up);
    if (angle < -5.0F)
        print("turn left");
    else if (angle > 5.0F)
        print("turn right");
    else
        print("forward");
```

So if anybody has an idea on how to implement it, please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like a linear algebra question, have you thought of modifying your question and submitting it to math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, thanks!